# Echo text on Contact Form 7 submit button click (WordPress)

Tags: php, wordpress, contact-form-7

I have put the attribute name on contact form 7 plugin. I am trying to run a query after submit button on CF7 is clicked. But first for testing purposes I am trying to echo the text.

This is the code I am using

```
<?php 
if (isset($_POST["cf7-submit"]))
   {
       echo 'test text';
   }

?>
```

I have edited the plugins submit modules and added to have the name 'cf7-submit'
I don't see my echo anywhere!

Comment: Did you check the html that is built and see if that name is actually in the form?

Comment: @Danny this is whats inside form: <form action="/bh-events/lorem-ipsum/#wpcf7-f2304-o1" method="post" class="wpcf7-form sent" novalidate="novalidate">
and this is inside submit button: <input type="submit" value="RESERVIREN" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-submit btn btn-default" name="cf7-submit">

Comment: What does print_r($_POST); show after submission?

Comment: it shows nothing! it looks like that part is not triggered at all...